# What is the cardinality of $\{f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}\ |\ \forall n f(n)\not = n\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I think the set $A= \{f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}\ |\  \forall n f(n)\not = n\}$ has the size of the continuum. Well $A\subseteq \omega^{\omega}$ so $|A|\leq|\omega^{\omega}|=2^{\omega}$. But I couldn't prove the reverse inequality directly neither find an injection between $2^{\omega}$ and $A$.

I know plenty ways of proving that $A$ is not enumerable (by diagonal arguments) but this doesn't tell me anything about the cardinality itself (just that it is $>\omega$)

Could you help me?

Comment: When you write $\omega$, I mostly think of the ordinal, not the cardinal. Then when you write $\omega^\omega$, I mostly think of ordinal exponentiation, not cardinal exponentiation. I would personally prefer $\aleph_0$ and $2^{\aleph_0}$. But maybe that's just me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $S_1 = \{f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}\ |\ \forall n, f(n)\not = n\}$, and let $S_2 = \{f \mid f : \Bbb N \to \{0,1\}\}$. Note that $S_2$ has the cardinality of the continuum. Consider how we might construct either an injective map $\phi:S_2 \to S_1$, or a surjective map $\phi:S_1 \to S_2$.

---

**Further Hint:** How could we (systematically) modify the function $g(n) = n$ to produce an element of $S_1$?

---

My solution: we could define an injection $\phi:S_2 \to S_1$ by
$$
\phi(f)(n) = n + (-1)^{f(n)}.
$$
Alternatively, we could define a surjection $\psi:S_1 \to S_2$ by
$$
\psi(f)(n) = \begin{cases}
1 & f(n) < n\\
0 & f(n) > n.
\end{cases}
$$
Interestingly, $\psi \circ \phi$ is the identity map $f \mapsto f$.

Comment: My obvious attemptive: let $\phi:S_2\to S_1$ be such that $\phi(f)(n)=f(n)$ if $n>1$ and $\phi(f)(0)=1$ and $\phi(f)(1)=0$... but this is not injective

Comment: or should I just shift the first two images?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "shift the first two images". Note that if you never "use" $f(0)$ or $f(1)$, then your function cannot be injective.

Comment: @Robson Does your accepting the answer mean that you were able to answer the question?

Comment: Yes, what I mean was $\phi(f)(n+2)=f(n)$ and $\phi(f)(0)=1$, $\phi(f)(1)=0$, which is injective

Comment: @Robson That's not what I had in mind, but it works.